# Switch pictures with visibility based on textbox value looks right but still got error

Tags: excel, vba

Got two picture that are supposed to switch from visibility true and false based on textbox value:

`If Val(Sheet1.Range("BookRead").Value) >= 5 Then`         <- Get error here

`Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderR").Visible = False`

`Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderNR").Visible = True`

`Else`

`Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderR").Visible = True`

`Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderNR").Visible = False`

`End If`

Getting crazy what am I doing wrong? Gets Error 1004

By reaching 5 or higher in the textbox should make RookieReaderR visible and RookieReaderNR invisible. But it doesnt work.

Comment: Error *on which line* ?

Comment: Do you set the `LinkedCell` property of textbox to `Sheet1.Range("BookRead")`?

Comment: @TimWilliams "If Val(Sheet1.Range("BookRead").Value) >= 5 Then" Gets error 1004

Comment: @taller LinkedCell?

Comment: I fixed it. Used: "Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("BookRead").TextFrame.Characters.Text" instead of "Sheet1.Range("BookRead").Value"

Comment: What's the description for error 1004?  Sorry, can't remember them all.  Think it's data type mismatch?

Comment: Welcome to SO!
It seems like you solved your own problem, so would you post an answer yourself and mark this solved? Besides that, you might want to take a look at [the markdown ref](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to help make formatted code a tad easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is the condition you are setting. I think that, as per your requirement, you want to show the `RookieReaderR` when the value is five or greater. Then you should change the conditions as follows:

```
If Val(Sheet1.Range("BookRead").Value) >= 5 Then
  Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderR").Visible = True
  Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderNR").Visible = False
Else
  Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderR").Visible = False
  Sheet1.Shapes("RookieReaderNR").Visible = True
End If
```

In this case, I have reversed the conditions for the Hide/Show of the Blocks as per your requirement. I think now you can achieve what you were looking for.

Comment: Right picture being changed is not the problem but rather that I get error 1004.